# Hololens device build fails to not finding Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I'm trying to build Unity application for Hololens device on Visual Studio 2017 and I'm getting the following errors:

```
Metadata file '...\GeneratedProjects\UWP\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass\bin\x86\Release\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll' could not be found
Metadata file '...\GeneratedProjects\UWP\Assembly-CSharp\bin\x86\Release\Assembly-CSharp.dll'
```

I'm aware of the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447300/hololens-apps-will-no-longer-build-cites-metadata-file-missing-and-c-sharp-fir) but uninstalling and installing the latest versions of both Unity and VS did not help. Neither did starting a completely new project. I'm using now the latest versions of Unity (2017.1.0f3) and Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.0).
I've tried uninstalling both applications. Everything was working fine yesterday but then I downloaded additional components to Visual Studio (ASP.NET) and the Hololens build stopped working. Any idea how I could fix the issue?

I can see the Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll in Unprocessed folder under the path it's searching for it and even tried to copy it to the correct path but it did not help. I have also tried to build the project without ticking the Unity C# Projects but I get a different error then.

**Update**

I found this post on Unity forums and I think it's the same issue I have: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/net-scripting-backend-and-visual-studio-2017-3-incompatibility.487833/

A workaround for this issue is to manually modifiying The "UAP,Version=v10.0.xxx" to "UAP,Version=v10.0" In the project.lock.json files of the GeneratedProjects.

Comment: Did your workaround work?

Comment: Yes it did. There are 3 different lock.json files which need the same fix. I do not have the project anymore on my computer so I cannot say the exact files but they should not be too hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions to this problem include a downgrade to Visual Studio 2015, or using the patch that the link you provided has.